# How Do You Show That There Exist Infinitely Many Organic Tautologies?

Tags: propositional-calculus

This question takes inspiration from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341348/prove-that-there-are-infinity-many-tautologies/1341546#1341546) question.

A tautology is organic if none of it's proper sub-formulas are tautologies.  In other words, if all of the sub-formulas excluding the formula itself are *not* tautologies.

For example, C C p q C C q r C p r is organic, but C p C q C r q is not, since C q C r q is a tautology.

I suspect that there exist infinitely many organic tautologies *which are not substitution instances of other tautologies*.  How might that get proved?

Comment: What notation are you using? I don't recognize it.

Comment: @PyRulez Polish notation.  http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/polish-notation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just expand your first formula by adding more variables? For instance

$$ (a\to(b\to c))\to((a\to d)\to((b\to d)\to(c\to d)) $$

or CCaCbcCCadCCbdCcd in Polish notation, should be an organic tautology if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You're right that this would work for what I asked.  I've edited the question to preclude using such substitution instances.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: I'm not sure I really know what a "substitution instance" is, but is $$ (a\to(b\to c))\to((a\wedge b)\to c)$$ allowed?

Comment: CCaCbcCCadCCbdCcd is not a tautology.  Let a = 0, b = 0, c = 1, and d= 0.  Then CaCbc = 1.  But, CCadCCbdCcd = CC00CC00C10 = CC00CC000 = CC00C10= CC000= C10 = 0.  A substitution instance **I** of a tautology **T** is simply a wff that we can obtain from **T** by substitution alone (*uniform* replacement of variables by formulas throughout the formula).  Your example is incorrect, but your idea works!  You just prefix the conditionals instead of what you did.  More like C CaCpq C CaCqr CaCpr, C CbCaCpq C CbCaCqr CbCaCpr, C CcCbCaCpq C CcCbCaCqr CcCbCaCpr...

Comment: The pattern there goes that you have Ca...CoCpq as the antecedent, Ca...CoCqr as the antecedent of the consequent, and Ca...CoCpr as the consequent of the consequent.  Since the consequent of the consequent has form Ca...CoCpr, we could assume Ca...CoCpq and Ca...CoCqr, and all variables in a ... p.  Then we have q, and finally r following.  Discharging all assumptions yields the formula as a tautology.  It's not organic, since the antecedent is not a tautology (nor does it contain any) and neither is the consequent of the consequent, nor the antecedent of the consequent.

Comment: And the consequent itself is not a tautology either, so none of the sub-formulas are tautologies, rendering all tautologies of this form organic.

Comment: Oh and extended forms of importation and exportation like you've suggested with your last comment should work also.